# Open file to run x time - linux terminal

Tags: linux, ubuntu, terminal

I want to create x instance of a .sh file. By exemple instad of open x terminals and enter ./.sh in everyone, I want to open then open autmatlicly all doing the same "*.sh" file run. Any way to do this?

I want all to work in same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to see the output of all running script at same time, You can use following command to open multiple tab in same gnome-window.

`gnome-terminal --tab -e "script.sh" --tab -e "script.sh" --tab -e "script.sh"`

To prevent gnome-terminal from exiting after its given command has exited, add exec bash at the end of each command.

`gnome-terminal --tab -e "script.sh; exec bash" --tab -e "script1.sh; exec bash" --tab -e "script.sh; exec bash"`

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can execute the scripts as many times as you want in the background (assuming that the script is not interractive which is probably the case as you want it to run 10 times at once). You will need two scripts for this. The first will be your original .sh that you want to run x times. The second script will be like this:

```
sh <your script>.sh &
sh <your script>.sh &
sh <your script>.sh &
sh <your script>.sh &
.
.
.
.
(x times)
```